TYPO3 10.4.6 - Validator for image upload dimesions and aspect ratio
I am using a Model with an instance variable attachedFile of type FileReference.
I don't want my users to be able to upload image files with huge dimensions.
Furthermore it should only be possible to upload file with the aspect ratio of 16/9.
I tried implementing a custom Validator, but it does not trigger.
Here is my approach:
namespace My\Namespace\Validation\Validator;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\PathUtility;

class ImageDimensionsValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    protected $supportedOptions = [
        'maxWidth' => [1000, 'Maximum allowed width', 'integer'],
        'maxHeight' => [1000, 'Maximum allowed height', 'integer'],
    ];

    protected function isValid($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof FileReference) {
            $file = $value->getOriginalFile();
            $filePath = PathUtility::getAbsoluteWebPath($file->getIdentifier());
            $imageSize = getimagesize($filePath);

            $maxWidth = $this->options['maxWidth'];
            $maxHeight = $this->options['maxHeight'];

            if ($imageSize[0] > $maxWidth || $imageSize[1] > $maxHeight) {
                $this->addError(
                    sprintf(
                        'The image dimensions are too large. Maximum allowed dimensions are %dx%d pixels.',
                        $maxWidth,
                        $maxHeight
                    ),
                    1620729248
                );
            }
        } else {
            $this->addError('Invalid file type.', 1620729249);
        }
    }
}


Instance variable in my model:
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("My\Namespace\Validation\Validator\ImageDimensionsValidator", options={"maxWidth"=1000, "maxHeight"=1000})
 * @Cascade("remove")
 */
protected $attachedFile = null;


I'm not sure how to register my new Validator properly in TYPO3 10.4.6
What other files to I need to edit? ext_localconf? tt_content?
Thank for you help!

How do you actually handle the file upload? Using a type converter?

$data= $this->myRepository->findByUid($id);
$data->getAttachmentFile(); // FileReference Object

There is a difference between huge dimensions and ratio. Huge dimensions and therefore huge file sizes can be converted with some extensions (tinyimg, imageoptimizer). For the correct ratio you can force the editors to use 16:9 only.

There is no need to register your validator. If you are in composer mode - Did you dump the autoload? Not sure, if your approach will work at all, because if you have an instance of FileReference, the file is already uploaded to your server.

You could also use EXT:image_autoresize (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/image_autoresize) to achive that. Not sure, if it can convert the 16:9 ratio though. But you should be able to implement a hook/event for that.

The validator will only be used when updating/saving data. In your case like Mogens indicated, if your file is already uploaded, the Validator won't really catch on to it. You have to do the validation before the actual persisting, and probably manually. For TYPO3v13 you may be able to use this cool thing here: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/83749
